# How to convert from decimal to a binary string?

Tags: python, binary, decimal

> The goal of this part of the lab is to motivate a right-to-left conversion of decimal numbers into binary form. Thus, you will end up writing a function numToBinary(anInteger) that works as follows:
>
> ```
> >>> numToBinary(5)
> '101'
> ```

The code I have is:

```
def isOdd (x):
    if x%2==1:
        return('True')
    if x%2==0:
        return('False')

def numToBinary(x):
    if n==0:
        return ''
    elif isOdd(x):
        return numToBinary(x//2)+'1'
    else:
        return numToBinary(x//2)+'0'
```

But this returns the string from left to right. Can anyone help me find a way to go from the left to right representation to a right to left representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this Python?

I don't see any "left-to-right" problem in your code. However, the function `isOdd` that you provided returns Strings (`'False'` and `'True'`). It should return Booleans (i.e. remove the single-quotes).

```
def isOdd (x):
    if x%2==1:
        return(True)  # <<< THIS
    if x%2==0:
        return(False) # <<< AND THIS
```

Also, you're using a variable named `n` inside `numToBinary`, which is not defined anywhere (it should be `x`, obviously)

```
def numToBinary(x):
    if x==0:          # <<<< THIS!
        return ''
    elif isOdd(x):
        return numToBinary(x//2)+'1'
    else:
        return numToBinary(x//2)+'0'
```

This code should work fine.

If you **just** want to convert a number to binary, you can use Python's internal `bin` function. Try: `bin(5)[2:]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the array. Here is my code. Hope you will get it and it will help you.

```
int numberArray[100], number, quo, rem, i=0, j;

cout << "Enter positive number : ";
cin >> number;

while(number > 0)
{
    quo = number/2; // quo defines the quotient.
    //cout << "\n" << quo;

    rem = number % 2; // rem defines the reminder.
    //cout << rem;

    numberArray[i] = rem;

    i++;
    number = quo;
}

cout << "Binary digits of entered number are : ";

// Below loop is for result of binary numbers, entered by user.
for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
{
    cout << numberArray[j];
}
```

Thank,
Adil